# Excel INDEX/MATCH formula with varying multiple criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

I have an INDEX/MATCH formula (excel 2010) that I'm using to return the first value based on two criteria, then the second value and so on. I would like to make the two criteria "optional"... So basically the user can enter one criteria and get the result that matches with just the one criteria, then add the second criteria if necessary to refine the result further... eventually I would like to do this with more than just two criteria (10 when complete). I'm not sure if something like this is even possible but it would be extremely helpful if it was.

This is the formula I've been using, as I mentioned it works great for matching both criteria but when one criteria is left empty it throws an error.

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX(July2017!$D:$D,SMALL(IF(($B$8=July2017!$C:$C)*($D$8=July2017!$B:$B),ROW(July2017!$D:$D)),ROW(1:1)),1),"")}
{=IFERROR(INDEX(July2017!$D:$D,SMALL(IF(($B$8=July2017!$C:$C)*($D$8=July2017!$B:$B),ROW(July2017!$D:$D)),ROW(2:2)),1),"")}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Why not use Advanced filters?

Comment: @ScottCraner I'm attempting to set up the sheet for various users, the criteria will be in drop down lists for the simplest user experience.

Comment: you can still use drop down lists and a button to kick off the advanced filter.

Comment: And?  You can still do that, and use vba based on the Worksheet_Change event to fill the data with Advanced Filter, it will be more robust than a bunch of array formula.

Comment: @ScottCraner I appreciate the suggestion and agree it's definitely a better solution... unfortunately I do not possess the greatest vba skills and wouldn't really know where to begin... formulas I'm pretty good with, vba code not as much...

Comment: It can be done with array formulas; Change each of your boolean `...($B$8=July2017!$C:$C)*...` to something like `(IF($B$8<>"",$B$8=July2017!$C:$C,1))*...` but putting 10 of these in one formula will cause the formula to do over 10.4 million calculations each.  So if you have more than 10-20 of these it will slow down the calcs to a crawl, and if too many more it will crash excel. To alleviate some of that limit your references to only the data set and not full columns.

Comment: Here is a good start on how to do this in vba: http://excelsemipro.com/2011/03/copy-data-to-another-worksheet-with-advanced-filter/

Comment: @ScottCraner Thank you so much the advanced filter suggestion, seems obvious now but you definitely got me looking in the right direction and it helped me significantly! Thanks again!